# Prometheus Python client library

Tags: python, monitoring, prometheus

I'm getting started with Prometheus to get trending data on a service I've built. I'm trying to use the Python client library, but I'm unclear as to how to use it.

Based on the "Getting started" docs there is a `prometheus.yml` file that points to the applications you want to monitor, and the Python client library has this code as an example.

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Summary
import random
import time

# Create a metric to track time spent and requests made.
REQUEST_TIME = Summary('request_processing_seconds', 'Time spent processing request')

# Decorate function with metric.
@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def process_request(t):
    """A dummy function that takes some time."""
    time.sleep(t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    start_http_server(8000)
    # Generate some requests.
    while True:
        process_request(random.random())
```

It looks like it starts up it's own server and isn't meant to be intertwined with the code in my services.

So my question is, how do I use the Prometheus client, to tell Prometheus exactly what functions to monitor from my services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add metrics such as the `Summary` in the example to your own code, and they'll be exposed on port 8000.

Comment: so then am I importing the `prometheus_client` into the code that I want to monitor? Or does it live as a separate service?

Comment: Yes, import it into every file that you want to instrument.